# Java Intro to Class And Objects

Tags: java, class, object, methods, void

An exercise in classes and objects that I was given to complete over the summer is driving me insane. I know it should be easy but for some reason, I can't get my head around it so I was hoping someone here could help?
Here's the briefing:

Write a class to represent a rectangle according to the specification below:

**Private members:**

- double width – width of the rectangle
- double height – height of the rectangle

**Public methods:**

- Rectangle() – default constructor which creates a rectangle of size 1
  by 1
- Rectangle (double w, double h) – constructor which creates a
  rectangle of specified width and height
- double area() – calculates and returns the area of a rectangle
- void scale(double factor) – scales a rectangle by a specified scale
  factor

Write a main program to create 3 rectangles: the first will use the default constructor, the second will be a
rectangle 2 x 3 and the third will be a rectangle 4 x 6. Print out the area of each rectangle and then scale
the first rectangle by 4 and the second by 0.5 and print out the new areas.

**I have also included the code I have written so far:**

```
package ac.uk.ljmu.s016classesandobjects;

public class T2Rectangle 
{
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public void Rectangle () { 
        // default constructor which creates a rectangle of size 1 by 1.
        width = 1;
        height = 1;
    }

    void Rectangle (double w, double h) { 
        // constructor which creates a rectangle of specified width and height.
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    double area() {
        // calculates and returns the area of a rectangle.
        return width * height;
    }

    void scale(double factor) {
        // scales a rectangle by a specified scale factor.

        // some sort of calculation involving factor * area?
    }
}
```

**This is the main method (for what little I've written):**

```
package ac.uk.ljmu.s016classesandobjects;

public class T2Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T2Rectangle R1 = new T2Rectangle();
        T2Rectangle R2 = new T2Rectangle();
        T2Rectangle R3 = new T2Rectangle();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance to any good-hearted Samaritans.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. You can't just dump your homework here and ask for general help.

Comment: what problem are you facing with the code?

Comment: The most obvious problem, is a constructor is **not** a method, it must have the same name as the class and it isn't `void`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your constructors from

```
public void Rectangle(...)
```

to

```
public T2Rectangle(...)
```

and for `scale()`

it should be something like this...

```
this.width *= factor;
this.height *= factor;
```

Comment: Honestly, I think renaming the class rather than the constructor would make more sense to promote re-use. I guess it's subjective here since it's homework though.